# Reading Danish in Pandas `read_csv`

Tags: python, pandas

Reading Danish in Pandas `read_csv`. I have several ways.

```
 pd.read_csv(file, sep  =";", encoding= 'utf_8')
```

will return an error: *utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 50: invalid continuation byte*

I looked at this https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings and tried with

```
 pd.read_csv(file, sep  =";", encoding= 'cp865')
```

Now it works but the danish characters (æøå) are not correct. For instance, when the data is supposed to say `Øvrige` it says `╪vrige`.

what should I do to properly read Danish characters?

I am using Spyder and `pd.__version__` is 1.0.5

Comment: I strictly believe you've to use iso-8859-1 instead of utf-8 to read Danish Characterset.

Comment: Which operating system and python editor are you using? Also what is your `pd.__version__`? This seems to be working fine for me with `encoding='utf_8'` on macOS using python 3.7.6 and pandas 1.1.2